# How to make Grails drop down readonly

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I had a requirement of making drop down read only in Grails gsp page. I had two gsp pages create and show. In create user select an element in drop down and submits the selection. In show.gsp, I would like to fetch and show the same element( element selected in create page ) and drop down must be readonly.

Example : 
Create.gsp : drop-down 1 2 3

User selected 3

Show.gsp : drop-down must be readonly with value 3

Comment: Why not just show the value as text?  Seems like an odd user experience to have a "show" page with nonfunctional select lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the input, this does mean the value won't be submitted but if this is a read only view it shouldn't matter, if it does you could add a hidden field for the real value

```
<g:select name="mySelect" from="${[1,2,3]}" value="3" disabled="disabled" />
```